# Why am I getting the wrong boolean returned when all other instances are correct?

Tags: java, oop, interface

Here's my `Rational` class:

```
package lab18f;

import static java.lang.System.*;

class Rational implements Comparable<Rational>
 {
//add two instance variables
private int num, den;

//write two constructors
public Rational ()
{
    num = 1;
    den = 1;
}

public Rational (int numer, int deno)
{
    num = numer;
    den = deno;
}

//write a setRational method
public void setRational(int numer, int deno)
{
    num = numer;
    den = deno;
}


//write  a set method for numerator and denominator
public void setNumerator(int numer)
{
    num = numer;
    
}

public void setDenominator(int deno)
{
    den = deno;
}
public void add(Rational  other)
{
    //num1/den1 + num2/den2 
    //new numerator = (num1 * den2 + num2 * den1)
    //new denominator = (den1 * den2)
    
    int newNumer = (this.getNumer()*other.getDeno() + other.getNumer()*this.getDeno());
    int newDeno = this.getDeno()*other.getDeno();
    this.setRational(newNumer, newDeno);
    
    reduce();
}

private void reduce()
{
    int gcd = 0;
    int numer = num;
    int deno = den;
    
    if(numer > deno)
        gcd = gcd(numer,deno);
    else if(numer < deno)
        gcd = gcd(deno, numer);
    else
        gcd = numer;
    
    this.setRational(num/gcd, den/gcd);
    
}

private int gcd(int numOne, int numTwo)
{
    
    int one = numOne;
    int two = numTwo;
    int gcd = two;
    
    
    if(two==0)
        return one;
    return gcd(two, one%two);
}

public Object clone ()
{
    return new Rational(num, den);
}


//ACCESSORS

//write get methods for numerator and denominator
public int getNumer()
{
    return num;
}

public int getDeno()
{
    return den;
}

public boolean equals( Object obj)
{
    Rational lhs = (Rational)obj;
    if((getNumer()/getNumer()== lhs.getNumer()/lhs.getNumer()) && getDeno()/getNumer() == lhs.getDeno()/lhs.getNumer())
        return true;
    return false;
}

public int compareTo(Rational other)
{


    return -1;
}




//write  toString() method
public String toString()
{
    return "" + getNumer() + "/" + getDeno();
}

}
```

and the runner class for the `Rational` class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Lab18f
 {
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Rational test = new Rational();
    out.println("test = " + test);

    Rational newOne = new Rational(3,4);
    out.println("newOne = "+newOne);

    out.println("test.equals(newOne) = "+test.equals(newOne));

    newOne = (Rational)test.clone();
    out.println("\n\nnewOne after test.clone() = "+newOne);
    out.println("test.equals(newOne) = "+test.equals(newOne));
    
    Rational rOne = new Rational(1,2);
    Rational rTwo = new Rational(2,3);
    out.println("1/2.equals(2/3) = "+rOne.equals(rTwo));
    test.setRational(4,6);
    out.println("2/3.equals(4/6) = "+rTwo.equals(test));
            
    out.println("\n\nrOne = "+rOne);
    out.println("rTwo = "+rTwo);

    out.println("rOne.compareTo(rTwo) = "+rOne.compareTo(rTwo));
    out.println("rTwo.compareTo(rOne) = "+rTwo.compareTo(rOne));

    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\nrOne.add(rTwo) = "+ rOne);

    rOne.setRational(1,2);
    rTwo.setRational(1,3);
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n1/2.add(1/3) = "+ rOne);
    
    rOne.setRational(4,10);
    rTwo.setRational(3,5);
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n4/10.add(3/5) = "+ rOne);  

    rOne.setRational(2,10);
    rTwo.setRational(3,6);
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n2/10.add(3/6) = "+ rOne);      

    //1/4 + 2/8 = 1/2
    rOne.setRational(1,4);
    rTwo.setRational(2,8);
    out.println("\n\n1/4.equals(2/8) = "+rOne.equals(rTwo));        
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n1/4.add(2/8) = "+ rOne);   
    
    //1/6 + 2/8 = 5/12
    rOne.setRational(1,6);
    rTwo.setRational(2,8);
    out.println("\n\n1/6.equals(2/8) = "+rOne.equals(rTwo));                
    rOne.add(rTwo);
    out.println("\n\n1/6.add(2/8) = "+ rOne);           
}
}
```

my issue at hand is that when I run the runner class (which obviously runs the `Rational` class) I have a statement like this in my output:

> test = 1/1
>
> newOne = 3/4
>
> test.equals(newOne) = true

which clearly the fraction 1/1 does not equal 3/4

Comment: what is your `equals` trying to do? The issue you have is you are doing integer division so it's going to truncate the number so 4/3 is 1 not 1.33 and of course 1/1 is 1.

Comment: the `equals` is supposed to check for an equal value between a fraction that is the primary (ie `test.equals(newOne)`), with `test` being the "primary", being equal to the part in the ()

Comment: I understand the `equals` usage what I don't know is what defines whether 2 fractions are equal? is it that that have the same decimal value or do they have to be the same fraction i.e. is 1/2 = 2/4?

Comment: @twain249, the second way you worded it, although, wouldn't it be the same either way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equals method doesn't appear to be doing what it's supposed to be doing.  For one, you are doing integer division, and you are dividing the numerator by itself.  Try multiplying the numerator of one and the denominator of the other and comparing it to the product of the numerator of the other and the denominator of the first one.  The [fractions are equal if those two products are equal](http://www.augustatech.edu/math/molik/fractionequivnotes.pdf).

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    Rational lhs = (Rational) obj;
    return ((getNumer() * lhs.getDeno()) == (getDeno() * lhs.getNumer()));
}
```

Comment: Ah! spot on! Thank you so much! I'll be sure and accept it once Stackoverflow allows